# Por qué una variable no toma un valor que le estoy asignando?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas tardes, estoy teniendo un problema asignándole un valor obtenido a través de una conexión TCP/IP a una variable, el programa no me tira ningún error, pero cuando llamo a la variable "mensaje" desde otra clase (o formulario) para volcarlo en un "label", no muestra ningún valor. ¿Por qué puede ser? Espero puedan ayudarme! Saludos.

(es una aplicación de Windows Forms en C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Conexion
{
    public static string mensaje = "Esperando el mensaje...";
    static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
    static Socket sck;
    [STAThread]


    public static void Exemys(/*string[] args*/)
    {

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.34.230"), 5202);
        try
        {
            sck.Connect(localEndpoint);
            MessageBox.Show("Exemys connected!\r\n");
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to Exemys\r\n");
            Exemys(/*args*/);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            Buffer = new byte[sck.SendBufferSize];
        int bytesRead = sck.Receive(Buffer);
        byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
        }
        string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            strData = mensaje;

    }
}
}
}
```

Éste es el código del formulario:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

public partial class formulario : Form

{

    public formulario()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = /*label1.Text + */Conexion.mensaje;
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Conexion.Exemys();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: No veo que en ningun lugar le asignas el valor de la variable mensaje.

Comment: @Einer este código lo tengo en un archivo de código aparte del formulario que quiero usar. Acá estoy declarando esta clase, y luego tengo un formulario que contiene un label, el cual quiero que tenga el valor de "mensaje". Lo que sucede en este código, es que le estoy asignando un valor a "mensaje" que sería el mismo que "strData", y cuando corro el programa y veo el formulario, el valor de "strData" que estoy pasando a través de la variable "mensaje" no aparece.

Comment: El valor que quieres asignar al label. Es obteniendo los datos mediante un socket?

Comment: @Einer exactamente, por cada segundo me llega un mensaje tipo string, eso es lo que quiero asignar al label.

Comment: Y que pasa con el valor? Esta llegando? O esta llegando incorrecto?

Comment: @Einer el valor llega perfecto, lo puedo chequear viéndolo a través del programa Hyperterminal.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,

Veo que tienes en la función `Exemys` tienes un bucle `while (true) { ... }` sin ningún punto de salida. Esto provoca que cuando pulses el botón del formulario, la función que se ejecuta nunca termina. Además, como ha dicho @David Zabaleta, estás leyendo lo que te llega por el socket en la variable `strData` pero luego lo estás machacando con el valor de `mensaje`.

Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033198/5308014) a ver si te sirve de ayuda

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y además asi ganar tu primera medalla. Creo que tu respuesta es correcta, bien visto. De todas maneras, en las respuestas es preferible poner los mínimos enlaces posibles, deberías copiar las partes más relevantes del enlace, aunque dejes este como referencia. Pásate por [answer]

Comment: Si, tenes razón en que el bucle `while` genera un problema. Igualmente, lo anulé y sigue sin aparecer el dato.
Y el `strData` lo asigné a `mensaje` porque no tengo forma de pasarlo al otro formulario. Intenté lo del enlace que me pasaste, pero no me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Eh, en tu linea final le asignas a strData el valor de mensaje. ¿No deberías hacerlo al revés?

```
 string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
        strData = mensaje;
```

Ok, tienes varias cosas raras en tu código, pero 'pa pronto'.

lo correcto es

```
string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            mensaje = strData;
```

y

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Conexion.Exemys();
        label1.Text = Conexion.mensaje;
    }
```

Comment: Ya lo probé, pero es lo mismo, sigue sin aparecer.

Comment: ¿Y cuando haces debug strData si trae el mensaje correcto?

Comment: Si, trae el mensaje correcto.

Comment: Ok, déjame revisar lo que acabas de actualizar en tu pregunta...

Comment: Disculpa hermano, pero sigue sin aparecer.

Comment: La aplicacion de consola no deberia hacer un return del mensaje?

Comment: Un segundo y publico nuevo código :)

Comment: Una duda,  ¿quieres que 'Conexion' sea otro formulario, o debe ser una clase sin interfaz?

Comment: @DavidZavaleta No no, quiero que conexión sea una clase sin interfaz. Es una clase que estoy utilizando para poder conectarme y obtener los datos.